# How to figure out why this process is terminated accidentally On Ubuntu16.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, memory, rsyslog, virtual-memory

I tried to run a python script which trains a lstm model on a server.

(figure 1 server's OS information.)

[image: Here is the server's os information.]

However,everytime before the traning ends,the process will be terminated.

(figure2&3 the screenshot of the terminated process)
[image: the screenshot of the terminated process]

[image: information of the terminated process & memory used]

But I found that the cmd 'ps -aux' isn't consistent to the cmd 'free -mt'&'vmstat -a'.

I suspect If the kernel killed the process (because the system ran out of memory).So I try to find the kernel log.

But there's no piece of log file that I want listing under /var/log.

[image: the listed files under /var/log]

Can anyone help me find what really happened in the running of the python script?

Or tell me how to find some logs recording why this process is terminated?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Please [edit] the post to copy the text here and apply code formatting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

If your script does not generate logs explicitly, you can redirect the standard output and errors(Traceback Calls) to a particular file by redirecting them.

```
name-of-your-script.py > /var/script.log 2>>&1
```

You may also find valuable information by using the `strace` utility.